# What's your experience with ICEfaces? How does it compare with Wicket?

Tags: wicket, icefaces

If you've written UIs in both Apache Wicket and ICEFaces, how do they compare?

My cursory look at ICEFaces suggests it provides more "out of the box", but perhaps it is more difficult to extend.

Which one leads to cleaner code and separation of concerns?

Is either faster to prototype in, or easier to code?

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Answer (score 1):

ICEFaces is a component library for JSF, you really should compare JSF to Wicket.

Wicket also has component libraries, check [WiQuery](http://code.google.com/p/wiquery/) for example.

Some pointers:

- [Reasons to choose Wicket over JSF and Spring MVC](http://www.infoq.com/news/2006/12/wicket-vs-springmvc-and-jsf)
- [JSF, Icefaces and custom components experiences](http://www.codegravity.com/programming/jsf-icefaces-and-custom-components-experiences)